# Como receber um array e retornar outro

Tags: javascript, array, array-push

Tenho a seguinte questão:

Necessitamos uma função maisMenos que receba um array e retorne outro com os seguintes três números:

na primeira posição, a fração de números que são positivos
na segunda posição, a fração de números que são zero
na última posição, a fração de números que são negativos
Por exemplo, maisMenos([1, 2, 0, -1]) deveria retornar [0.5, 0.25, 0.25], devido a que há 50% de positivos, 25% de zeros, e 25% de negativos.

DICA
Algumas perguntas que poderiam ajudar: Como poderia passar um array e perguntar a cada elemento se é positivo, negativo ou zero? Como poderia contabilizar os elementos? Como construir o array resultante com estes valores?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 4):

Seja bem vindo a comunidade e ao mundo vasto da programação. Segue a solução com as explicações:

```js
var numeros = [1, 2, 0, -1]; //O Array de números fornecido pela questão
maisMenos(numeros); //Enviando o array para a função

function maisMenos(numeros) {
  /* Utilizando a função 'length' para obter a quantidade de elementos
  do array recebido como parâmetro */
  var quantidade = numeros.length;

  //Inicializando os contadores 
  var positivos = 0;
  var zeros = 0;
  var negativos = 0;

  /*Percorrendo cada elemento do array para verificar se é um número
    positivo, negativo ou zero */
  for (i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] > 0) {
      positivos = positivos + 1; //Caso seja positivo, some mais 1
    } else if (numeros[i] < 0) {
      negativos = negativos + 1; //Caso seja negativo, some mais 1
    } else {
      zeros = zeros + 1; //Caso seja zero, some mais 1
    }
  }

  //Calculando as frações
  positivos = positivos / quantidade;
  zeros = zeros / quantidade;
  negativos = negativos / quantidade;
  
  //Criando o novo array que exibirá os resultados fracionados
  var array = [positivos, zeros, negativos];

  //Exibindo o array com os resultados no console do navegador
  console.log(array);

  return array;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo ! funcionou perfeitamente !

Comment: @DiegoHonório Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de marcar uma resposta como aceita. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0):

Segue a resposta. Recebe a variável de arrayEntrada e retorna um array de saída (não joguei dentro de uma variável, mas é bem simples).

```
function inverterArray(arrayEntrada) {
    var totalElementos = arrayEntrada.length;
    var fracaoPositivo = 0;
    var fracaoNegativo = 0;
    var fracaoNula = 0;

    // Como poderia contabilizar os elementos
    arrayEntrada.forEach(function(valor) {
        if (valor > 0) {
            fracaoPositivo++;
        } else if (valor < 0) {
            fracaoNegativo++;
        } else {
            fracaoNula++;
        }
    });

    // Como construir o array resultante com estes valores
    return [(fracaoPositivo / totalElementos), (fracaoNula / totalElementos), (fracaoNegativo / totalElementos)];
}
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo, Funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de resolver isso é utilizando o `Math.sign()` do javascript, ficaria uma resolução parecida com a do nosso amigo acima. Segue o exemplo:

```
let valores = [1,2,0,-1];
let positivos = [];
let negativos = [];
let nulos = [];
let tamanho = valores.length;

for (let i = 0; i < tamanho ; i++) {
    let x = Math.sign(valores[i]);
    if (  x == 0  ) {
        nulos.push(i);
    } else if ( x == 1 ) {
        positivos.push(valores[i]);
    } else {
        negativos.push(valores[i]);
    }
}

let resposta = [(positivos.length/tamanho) , (negativos.length/tamanho) , (nulos.length/tamanho)];
```